# Make a javascript function instead variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, variables

Here I have a code that create a sidebar:

```
var side_bar_html = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[" + parseInt(gmarkers.length - 1) + "],\"click\");'>" + place.name + "</a><br>" + '<div class="raty" />' + "</br>";

$(side_bar_html).appendTo('#side_bar').filter('.raty').raty({
    score : place.rating,
    path : 'http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img'
})
```

How I can create a function from this code to create a sidebar with function ...

So something like that:

```
function Create_a_sidebar_and_put_it_into_ID#sidebar () {
//for every marker to return html string
 return "<div class='element'>"+place.name+"</br>"+place.rating+"</div>" + etc...
```

Becouse I have a problem with creating html, I dont know what to append where and I dont have contol over that

Is it possible?

Comment: 1. Put code in function, 2. Invoke function, 3. ???, 4. PROFIT

Comment: Just do 3. It's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're asking how you can take your first code block that creates a rating for a certain place, and refactor it so that you can arbitrarily create sidebars for places at will. So that's how I'll approach this answer.

As @Sime Vidas mentioned, you can start by taking the code that creates the sidebar itself and making that a function such as that below. I've modified the function a bit to take the javascript out of the `href` attribute (which is generally considered a bad practice) and replaced passing an html string into `$.fn.init` (which I've found steeply degrades performance) with using DOM methods to create elements. You also don't need the `<br />` after your `a` element because `div`s by default are block elements.

```
function createSidebar(place) {
    var $sidebarLink = $(document.createElement('a'));
    var $raty = $(document.createElement('div'));

    $sidebarLink.attr('href', '#').text(place.name).click(function(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        google.maps.events.trigger(gmarkers[parseInt(gmarkers.length - 1, 10)], 'click');
    });
    $raty.addClass('raty').raty({
        score: place.rating,
        path: 'http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img'
    });
    return $([$sidebarLink, $raty]);
}
```

Now you can do things like

```
var $sidebar = $('#side_bar');
places.map(createSidebar).forEach(function($sidebarPart) { 
    $sidebar.append($sidebarPart);
});
```

Sorry if I'm off track with answering your question, but I think this is what you were asking. If not feel free to leave a comment and we can talk about it more!